# Woocommerce product subtitle is misplaced

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Hey everyone I hope you can help me with this.
I created 2 subtitles with ACF for my products (subtitle and subtitle_2)
I want them to appear underneath my Product title (duh!!) on both my product page, and my homepage/shop (in the product "little box").

So far I managed to have them appear on the product page, by editing my single-product.php file but they're not in the right spot and I have no idea how to move them to where I want. I think they're considered as subtitles of the Page title rather than subtitles if the Product title.
(and as for the homepage, they don't appear at all but let's sort out 1 problem at a time)

Here is what I get and the actual code :
[image: subtitles misplaced]

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single products.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

 get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
    <div id="page-title">       
        <div class="width-container">
            <h3><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display')) {
                    echo '<div id="bread-crumb">';
                    bcn_display();
                    echo '</div>';
            }?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- close #page-title -->
<?php endif; ?>


    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_field('subtitle'); ?>
    <?php the_field('subtitle_2'); ?>

        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

</div>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

and here is a link to the corresponding product page : http://tinyurl.com/pzum42k

Any help would be much appreciated !!
Thanks in advance,
G

Comment: The red ring marked 'where the subtitles appear' has nothing inside it. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Graham : actually it does. you might not see it if you don't click on the image and enlarge it as the text is grey on black but the subtitles are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing them out in `single-product.php`, echo them out in `content-single-product.php`.

In other words, move what you have in `single-product.php` into the latter.

In `content-single-product.php`, add the subtitles above `<div class="summary entry-summary">`. How you want to style them is up to you, but placing them within `<p>`-tags will at least have them display each on one line.

Heres a snippet from `content-single-product.php` after the new addition:

```
(...)    

<?php echo '<p>' . get_field('subtitle') . '</p>'; ?>
<?php echo '<p>' . get_field('subtitle_2') . '</p>'; ?>

<div class="summary entry-summary">

(...)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @danjah !! Just to make sure : if I indeed want to place them right inside my <div class="summary entry-summary">, where exacltly should I place it : within the *hooked woocommerce lines?? it seems weird. here is my content-single-product.php file : http://pastie.org/10637791

Comment: No problem. That would be line 44 in your code. You would probably also have to place either a <div>, <span> or whatever around it, to be able to style the subtitles.

Comment: That is, you could also style the <p>-tags, of course.. :)

Comment: I just did all of that but weirdly, the subtitles don't appear but it created a big empty space above the title and changed the width of the "summary entry-summary". my new content-single-product.php file : http://pastie.org/10637845#1,42 and the page : http://tinyurl.com/pzum42k

Comment: I see.. Just so I get things straigth, does subtitle and subtitle_2 contain one value only, that are to be displayed on all posts, or are the values created within the post editor and different in every single post?

Comment: You know what, forget it, I'm updating my answer in a sec.

Comment: the values are created within the product editor and are different for every single product. to tell you everything my end goal is to go from this : http://postimg.org/image/xgxruan0t/ to this : http://postimg.org/image/s3tq0wdo1/ on my homepage (and obviously this would be reflected on the product page as well)

Comment: Ah, I see. You could try again now, I've updated my answer. Basically you should just move the code, although I've added some tags to get you the wanted line break.

Comment: thank you again so much for your time !! I will try that now and let you know.

Comment: oups !! I think I might have done something wrong... here is what my product page looks like : http://postimg.org/image/6w4kovqhb/ !!! lol would you mind telling me what I did wrong there : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/013cb813c863a954ed39 ? If that's not enough and as I don't want to abuse your time and kindness, I might offer to pay you to actually make the edits yourself.

Comment: Heh, that wasnt looking too good, no. This is the complete code: http://pastie.org/10638070

Comment: wahoo !! we're definitely getting there !! the subtitles appear underneath the line and just above the title now (see: http://tinyurl.com/pzum42k) . with a bit of css I could even live with that (even if ideally they would be under the title). but they still appear together on the same line tho. shall I simply add a CSS "display: block"? I was serious about paying you as I still have to make some edits to have them appear on the "product boxes" (on homepage/shop) like on that image : postimg.org/image/s3tq0wdo1. would you be interested?

Comment: Right, seems like there might be some hooks you could use to get them within the post, between the header and summary, but I'm not quite sure. I haven't used WooCommerce before. Anyway, thanks for the offer, but I currently have two ongoing projects taking up all my available time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help anyway !! You rock !!